# protocol https not supported or disabled in libcurl (although https is actually included)

Tags: linux, curl, libcurl, ubuntu-18.04

I'm installing Geant4 (a c++ package for physics) on Ubuntu 18.04. When I did "make" with cmake, it throws this error:

```
  error: downloading 'https://cern.ch/geant4-data/datasets/G4ABLA.3.1.tar.gz'
  failed

    status_code: 1
    status_string: "Unsupported protocol"
    log: Protocol "https" not supported or disabled in libcurl
```

---

After searching on stack overflow, I found someone else had similar problem before. As suggested by the answer of that existing problem, I recompiled curl with openssl, then protocol "https" is now included in curl, as I got this when did `curl -V` in the terminal:

```
$curl -V
curl 7.45.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.45.0 OpenSSL/1.0.2l zlib/1.2.11
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps pop3 pop3s rtsp smb smbs smtp smtps telnet tftp 
Features: IPv6 Largefile NTLM NTLM_WB SSL libz TLS-SRP UnixSockets
```

However, when I tried to do `make` again, the same error occurred. I did `make clean` and restarted my computer but it doesn't work. How to solve this problem?

Comment: Perform `command -v curl`. Is that the cURL you expect?

Comment: When I did `command -v curl` I got 
`/home/waterbarque/anaconda3/bin/curl`,
which is different from the curl I expected...it must be the reason for the error. What should I do to fix this? Thx

Answer (score 0):

As already hinted in the comments make sure you have the correct `curl` installed. Use `apt-get show curl` to see if the package is installed. If it isn't installed, do `sudo apt-get install curl`.
The binary should be e.g. under `/usr/bin/curl`. If it is and you still use the wrong `curl` binary, if you type curl, then check by `echo $PATH` (and adapt) your PATH environment variable.

Answer (score -2):

In order to get this to work, I had to install `curl` with SSL, as is mentioned in [this blog](https://itectec.com/ubuntu/ubuntu-protocol-https-not-supported-or-disabled-in-libcurl/).